# Parse fields with multiple delimiters in HUNK

Tags: splunk

I am using HUNK 6.1.1. I have the data in the below format in a csv file,

Description= ABC

MyID= 001

MyCount= 95

TimeStamp: 2013-07-03T04:14:38

All_Info= [FREE_TEXT] Last update : 11-07-13 00:02:49 Reset date : 10-05-09 00:31:26 test time : 30.316 s test counter : 1181.0

I have loaded the data from my HDFS location by creating a simple provider and index using csv loader, but i want to further parse the "All_Info" field to extract the field-values (Last update,Reset date,test time & test counter) from it. The "All_Info" Column doesnt have a spefic delimiter.

How can I further parse the "All_Info" field so that I can use the field-values in it to generate some aggregates on these?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the regular expression field extractors (`rex`). Check out the splunk documentation [here](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.1.2/SearchReference/Rex).